# split value of field in solr to compare with another value

Tags: loops, solr, dataimporthandler

I'm new in Solr.
I have fields in Solr from MySQL JDBC dataimport. The value of database column for that field is "test,test2,test3". If I choose fieldtype in Solr

1. Fieldtype is strings and the value is ["test,test2,test3"].
2. Fieldtype is string and the value is "test,test2,test3"

I want to access each value in Solr to compare with "another string". So "test1" compare to "another string", "test2" compare to "another string", so on. How can I do that in Solr? maybe its query or something? Using loop or something or some tricky?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different fieldtype that has a tokenizer which splits on commas. In your case, you can add something like this to the relevant portions of your schema:

```
<types>
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="comma_separated">
    <analyzer>
         <tokenizer class="solr.SimplePatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=","/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>

<fields>
<field name="my_comma_separated_field" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" type="comma_separated" />
</fields>
```

Now, when you index to the `comma_separated` field, your values will be split by commas, and you'll be able to search on each one of them.

PS. add other filters as you require to your fieldType definition.

You can find the tokenizer documentation [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-SimplifiedRegularExpressionPatternTokenizer)

Comment: actually I find solution. I split that string when retrieve (select * from table) through database and make fields in Solr schema to handle each splitted string. Fortunately, I just have 3 string separated by comma. Anyway, your solution seems to work, but I have not tried this solution, maybe next time. But thanks for the solution

Comment: Please try this solution and only then accept it as it could otherwise be misleading to others who might refer to this question.